# Is there any PHP function like MYSQL IN?

Tags: php, function

We can check in MYSQL for example `SELECT * FROM smth WHERE id IN(1,2,3)` and select things where id 1, 2 or 3.

Is it possible to do it in PHP? To change this line:

```
if($_GET['mi'] == 4 || $_GET['mi'] == 5) { 
   do_something(); 
}
```

into a shorter line? Like `if($_GET['mi'] in(1,2,3)) { true(); }`

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if(in_array($_GET['mi'], array(4, 5)) { do_smth(); }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$in = array(1,2,3);
if(in_array($_GET['mi'], $in)) { true(); }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(in_array($_GET['mi'), array(4, 5)) { do_smth(); }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use PHP's [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function. You just need to create an array first.

```
$arr = array(1,2,3);
if (in_array($_GET['mi'], $arr))
{
  true();
}
```